# Visual Studio plugin to show keys pressed

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, pair-programming

My team is beginning to embrace pair programming and some of us are more familiar with Resharper (and other productivity tools) than others.  I was watching a DNR TV episode with Mark Miller and there was a Visual Studio plugin he had that showed which keys were pressed.  I think this would be a great plugin to have while pairing, as well as doing presentations with other developers.  You can see the plugin in action [here](http://perseus.franklins.net/dnrtvplayer/player.aspx?ShowNum=0107).

Does anyone know if this plugin is publicly available?  If not, is there another one similar to it that is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Key Jedi](http://osherove.com/tools) (under the **Other** section) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think that is what I'm looking for, but when I try to download I get an "Invalid hostname" error.  Do you have an alternative link?

Answer (score 3):

I also stumbled upon **CodeNinjaSpy** extension, which displays commands with shortcuts rather than individual shortcut keys.

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dd3ccb44-a46c-4b42-9c56-7d4aa526979f
- http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Helping-others-become-Visual-Studio-Keyboard-Ninjas-with-the-Code-Ninja-Spy