# Visual Studio: "Learn this keyboard shortcut" recommendation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio, its quicker if you use keyboard shortcuts rather than the mouse.

However, I'm not sure which keyboard shortcuts to learn!

Is there some way to track the most common mouse actions I've used today, so I can learn the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: When you start getting annoyed and thinking "I wish there was a shortcut for this", look it up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526803/visual-studio-plugin-to-show-keys-pressed

Comment: In theory, a Visual Studio extension should be able to track and log all commands issued, which you can then use to tally which commands you use most. In practice, I have no idea to write such a thing and any answer that fully covers it would undoubtedly be too broad.

Comment: @Ben This would work. However, sometimes intuition is not enough. If I knew for sure the #1 mouse action that I used today, I can put effort into learning that combo.

Answer (score 3):

This extension may help, as you carry out actions it highlights the shortcut you could have used:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.LearntheShortcut

Comment: Nice! It actually logs the shorts into the `Output..Learn This Shortcut` window, and this can be analyzed to find the most used shortcut over time. See my answer for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me.

Install "Learn the Shortcut":

[image]

Then, you can track all of your keypresses over time by looking at the log:

[image]

It would be relatively trivial to analyze this log to see which keypresses are the most common, some custom SQL should do the trick.